# Output single post tag in Wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I'm editing theme templates for category and tag archive pages in WordPress and have successfully printed the category using the following.

```
    <div class='avia-section-search'>
    <div class='container'>
    
    <?php 
    echo "<h2 class='entry-content-wrapper'>Level: ";
    global $post;
    $postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    if ( ! empty( $postcat ) ) {
    foreach ($postcat  as $nameCategory) {
    echo $nameCategory->name .' ';   
        }                                      
    }
            "</h2>";

    ?>
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

I've adjusted the code for tags but it's printed all the tags for the post

```
    global $post;
    $posttags = get_the_tags( $post->ID );
    if ( ! empty( $posttags ) ) {
    foreach ($posttags  as $nameTags) {
    echo $nameTags->name .' ';   
        }                                      
    }
```

Ideally I need to print only the current tag selected by the user.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: The WP functions will get all tags associated with a post, it doesn't know which one to get unless you tell it. How is the user selecting the tag? Is the tag in the URL, and if so can you show me an example of the url, and also which template file this is using, so I get a better understanding of your set up?

Comment: That makes sense. Yes the tag is in the URL using the custom structure option in WordPress settings, ie /tag/international/

I'm using archive.php and tag.php to implement.

Comment: Hi @RichardSlade Was the below answer helpful to you? If so, please select a "correct" answer *(by clicking the checkmark beside an answer)* to close the question, or provide an answer yourself and choose that as the correct answer. Otherwise, please add comments below the answer or edit your original question to add more detail so that additional assistance can be provided. That will help us out. *(Also remember that upvoting is encouraged in order to reward answers that were particularly informative - and it is possible to also upvote the answer that you checkmark.)* Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen, the WP functions return all tags on a post because they don't know which one to get. What we need to do is get the tag that was used to get the posts being displayed.

There are 2 ways to do this:

**1. Get the tag name using the [`single_tag_title()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_tag_title/)**
This will echo the title for the tag to the screen by default, e.g.:

```
<h1><?php single_tag_title(); ?></h1>
```

...or you can pass in `false` as the 2nd parameter to prevent it from being output so that you can save it as a variable.

```
<?php $title = single_tag_title('', false); ?>
```

**2. Get all details for the tag:** 
The archive page (as you are using, or another page if it is being used) will have executed a query that uses the slug of the selected tag. This means we can get the queried object.

In this case we get a [`WP_Term` object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) which has details of the term info query such as slug, tag id etc.:

```
    $page_tag = get_queried_object();

    // now you can do whatever you want with the tag, e.g. 
    $tag_name =   $page_tag->name;  
    $tag_slug =   $page_tag->slug;  
    $tag_id =     $page_tag->term_id;  
    $tag_parent = $page_tag->parent;
```

---

**UPDATE**: Using your own code that you added to the question:

**1. single_tag_title()**

```
<div class='avia-section-search'>
  <div class='container'>   
    <h2 class='entry-content-wrapper'><?php single_tag_title(); ?></h2> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**2. get_queried_object()**

```
<div class='avia-section-search'>
  <div class='container'>   
    <h2 class='entry-content-wrapper'>
        <?php 
        $page_tag = get_queried_object();
        echo $page_tag->name; // echo the tag name
        ?>
    </h2> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Having trouble getting it to work through. I'm not great at PHP so not sure where to place both solutions. Had a go at adapting but kept getting errors.

Comment: @RichardSlade You should be able to add this in the same place you add the code in your question - it sounds like it might just be a syntax error where you are adding it. If you edit your question to include few lines of code that surround the code you want to replace, I can show you what you need to add.

Comment: OK thanks I've updated the code that is being used for categories. I'm using a theme called Enfold which has some specific php requirements.

Comment: @RichardSlade I've updated my answer with the code you can use to replace the existing code that creates the heading - let me know if this works or if you need more help!

Comment: excellent it works perfectly, thank you for your help.